# MongoDB: How can I filter a collection by an array of arrays using $all operator

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In my MongoDB document I have an attribute that is an array of arrays and looks like this:

```
[
["option1", "option2"], ["option3", "option4"]
]
```

I have an aggregation pipeline that needs to filter Documents by this attribute, using nested arrays. For example, I need this kind of query:

```
{
$elemMatch: {
   $all: ["option3", "option4"]
}
}
```

I want to get those documents where one of nested arrays contains all elements from provided list.
But for some reason this query doesn't work and always returns empty result. Adding another $elemMatch works for other type of filters (`$in` for example), but in this case gives the same result:

```
{
$elemMatch: {
   $elemMatch: {$all: ["option3", "option4"]}
}
}
```

I want to understand, why those two operators do not work with each other? Can I still construct this query without using complex $project operations?

**UPD**: also important to mention, that the actual nested array in Document can be bigger than the one in the query, it can be `["option3", "option4", "option5"...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why `$all` doesn't work in your attempt is because you are comparing the outermost array (i.e. array of arrays to array of strings).

You can use `$map` the array of arrays to a boolean array with `$setIsSubset` to see if the array contains your input array elements. Then use `$anyElementTrue` for filtering.

```js
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$anyElementTrue": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$arr",
        "as": "a",
        "in": {
          "$setIsSubset": [
            // your input here
            [
              "option3",
              "option4"
            ],
            "$$a"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yw1iW-RxVcc)

Comment: Thanks!
I've also found that this query works too:
```
$match: {
      "arr": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          $all: [
            {
              $elemMatch: {
                $in: ["option3"]
              }
            },
            {
              $elemMatch: {
                $in: ["option4"]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

But I guess, your proposal is a cleaner solution.